# Is there anyway to return int and null with nested conditions?

Tags: linq, lambda

I want to return a customer which is in this city and buy ItemID = 1, 2 or NULL

```
List<int?> AcceptableValues = new List<int?>
{
    1,2
};      
        
List<Customer> Customers = ListOfCustomer.Where(x => x.CountryTbl.City == 1
                                    && x.ItemTbl.Any(p => p.ItemID == 1 || p.ItemID ==2 || p.Item is null)
                                    && x.SellTbl.SellType == 10).ToList();
```

Is there any way we can use LINQ to filter the customer who only buys itemID in the AcceptableValues ?
I've tried with `ItemTbl.SingleOrDefault`, or `ItemTbl.Where`, or `AppeptableValues.Contains(m => m.ItemID)` but didn't work.

Comment: what about `x.ItemTbl.Any(p => AcceptableValues.Contains(p.ItemID)|| m.Item == null)`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Customer> Customers = ListOfCustomer
    .Where(c => c.CountryTbl.City == 1
        && c.ItemTbl.Any(i => i.ItemID == null || AcceptableValues.Contains(i.ItemID))
        && c.SellTbl.SellType == 10).ToList();
```